# Troubleshooting "Error: Unable to serialize database:" when performing dumpdata

Tags: mysql, database, django, models

For some reason today I cannot dump my database using `python manage.py dumpdata` or from a link that can download the mysql file.

I tried to use `python manage.py dumpdata --traceback` and here is the information I have.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py", line 114, in handle
    use_natural_keys=use_natural_keys)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 91, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 48, in serialize
    self.handle_fk_field(obj, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 48, in handle_fk_field
    related = getattr(obj, field.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 301, in __get__
    raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist
```

It says `django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist`. I wonder if it has something to do with a Foreign key or something.

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    website = models.URLField(verify_exists = False)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    note = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

From my models.py, the field user, datetime and note were added recently. Now if for a client, any of these fields do not have a value i.e. blank, I will get the error `Unable to serialize database`.

When I have looked up user, dateime and note in mysql. The table for Client shows user_id, datetime and note to have Null values (which is what I want).  Why does it not allow Null values?

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| name      | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| telephone | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| website   | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| fax       | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| email     | varchar(75)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| is_active | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| user_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| datetime  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| note      | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Foreign key issue sounds like a good bet.  Any of your models have ForeignKey fields pointing to models in `django.contrib.auth.models`?

Comment: I second @tcarobruce. It sounds like a foreign key or constraint issue. I've had similar situations happen because of missing keys or constraints that didn't get properly modified by South or by hand.

Comment: `self.handle_fk_field(obj, field)` is a bit of a giveaway

Comment: As others stated, most likely some foreign key elements are missing in your table. I've had this problem as well. You can always dump data from another model to see if this problem is only for one model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell Django that it should allow NULL values on those recently added fields. It looks only at the fields definition, it doesn't fetch the schema from the database.

The `self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist` error is most likely raised when a client doesn't have an user associated and `client.user` is accessed. It's because by default all fields are required. If you change your model definition as shown bellow, the error should go away.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    # ...
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User, 
                             null=True, blank=True) 
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,
                             null=True, blank=True)
    note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

- `null=True` allows `NULL` respectively `None` values on a field.
- `blank=True` allows you to leave the the field empty in a model form
  (eg. in the admin).

(`blank` and `null` are both `False` by default)